# How to run johnny-five on Ubuntu 15.04?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu-15.04, johnny-five

```
$ node hello.js 
1436894483255 Device(s) /dev/ttyUSB0  
1436894483279 Connected /dev/ttyUSB0  
1436894493287 Device or Firmware Error A timeout occurred while connecting to the Board. 

Please check that you've properly flashed the board with the correct firmware. 

See: https://github.com/rwaldron/johnny-five/wiki/Getting-Started#trouble-shooting 
events.js:87
      throw Error('Uncaught, unspecified "error" event.');
            ^
Error: Uncaught, unspecified "error" event.
    at Error (native)
    at Board.emit (events.js:87:13)
    at Board.log (/usr/lib/node_modules/johnny-five/lib/board.js:623:8)
    at Board.(anonymous function) [as error] (/usr/lib/node_modules/johnny-five/lib/board.js:634:14)
    at Board.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/johnny-five/lib/board.js:407:12)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:119:15)
```

I have installed node and johnny-five on Ubuntu and connected Arduino Nano. But it's throwing the above error.

Comment: Did you also install the Firmata firmware, as explained on the page that the error message is linking to?

Answer (score 1):

before you run your node app, try to open arduino:

`$ arduino`

go to to file > Examples > Firmata, and choose **StandardFirmata**

once it opens **upload it** to your arduino.

when done, you should be able to run your node app without any problems

Answer (score 0):

The arduino IDE might be holding the connection to the board. Try closing it.